# I want to change the width of a table <td> to match the width of a non-repeat background photo

Tags: css, html, html-table

I have a table where the background photo is in . This photo is a no-repeat photo. So when the no-repeat code goes into action, it cuts some of the width of where normally a repeated photo would show at.

I want to have my blue  below it match the size of the no-repeat photo. It currently matches the repeatable photo width, but not the no-repeat width. Anyone have ideas on how to fix this?

I am creating this on a table due to email template constraints.

```
        <TABLE style="width: 80%; border: none; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; color: white;"><!-- width="80%" BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0" align="center" -->
                <TR WIDTH="997" HEIGHT="326" background="https://image.ibb.co/dO1HfQ/dog3edit.jpg" style="background-image:url(https://image.ibb.co/dO1HfQ/dog3edit.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;">

                    <TD>


                    <FONT class="titletext" color="white" align="center" style="width: 800px;
                    font-size: 50px;"><b>WELCOME TO ROVER!</b></FONT><br><br> 
                    <FONT class="subtitletext" color="white" align="center" style="width: 100px;
                                font-size: 30px;">Ready to get started?</FONT><br><br><br>

                    <a href="#"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/nvbiLQ/button.png" alt="Button" border="0"></a>

                    </TD>

                </TR>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:80%; background:blue">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </TABLE>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the max-width of the table to 997px to match the width of the row that contains the image.

Comment: This does work! Thank you very much. I amt trying to keep this website responsive so unfortunately I want to keep the weight a percentage size of 80% so when a handheld device looks at it it will resize accordingly. Is there any other way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Make the table data (`td`) tag fill the parent area:

```
td {
   width:100%;
}
```